# Using Update Throttle in AsyncTaskLoader in Android

Tags: android, loader, asynctaskloader

I am planning to use AsyncTaskLoader for my upcoming project. I have learned about Loader Callbacks, Loader Manager and AsyncTaskLoader.

I have also learned how to implement the asynctaskloader to perform network operation. But, I also want to show latest live feeds from server in my UI just like facebook does.

I have come across `setUpdateThrottle() in asynctaskloader`. I want to use `setUpdateThrottle` in my project, but I dont know how to use it. I have not come across any satisfactory resources in the web that could tell me how to use it, even official Android Blog does not clarify how to use setUpdateThrottle in asynctaskloader.

So, if anyone has successfully used `setUpdateThrottle in asynctaskloader`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you see this example !!!!!!?

http://blog.gunawan.me/2011/10/android-asynctaskloader-exception.html

see this part in above link

```
private final LoaderCallbacks< AsyncResult < List < String >>> loaderCallbacks = new LoaderCallbacks< AsyncResult< List < String >>>() {

        @Override
        public Loader< AsyncResult < List < String>>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            MyAsyncTaskLoader loader = new MyAsyncTaskLoader(TestActivity.this);
            loader.setUpdateThrottle(1000);

            return loader;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader < AsyncResult < List < String >>> loader, final AsyncResult< List < String >> result) {

            Exception exception = result.getException();
            if (exception != null) {
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // process the result
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader < AsyncResult < List < String >>> loader) {
            loader.reset();
        }
    };
```

Comment: thanks for the reply........will go through the block then only accept the answer